# Bokeh: Why does factor_cmap work in vbar but not in line?

Tags: python, categories, bokeh

I have trouble understanding how to map categorical data to colors in bokeh. 
I create a sample data frame that look like

```
                   A    B
2000-01-31  0.357440  baz
2000-02-29  0.377538  foo
2000-03-31  1.382338  bar
2000-04-30  1.175549  baz
2000-05-31 -0.939276  baz
2000-06-30 -1.143150  bar
2000-07-31 -0.542440  baz
2000-08-31 -0.548708  baz
2000-09-30  0.208520  bar
2000-10-31  0.212690  bar
2000-11-30  1.268021  foo
2000-12-31 -0.807303  bar
2001-01-31 -3.303072  bar
2001-02-28 -0.806650  baz
2001-03-31 -0.360329  baz
```

Below is an (adapted) minimal example where a bar chart is used and the color is chosen automatically be using `factor_cmap`:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Dark2
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
import numpy as np
import pandas.util.testing as pdt
import random

pdt.N, pdt.K = 15, 1  # Module-level default rows/columns
np.random.seed(444)

df = pdt.makeTimeDataFrame(freq='M')

#random.choices(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], k=len(df))
df['B'] = random.choices(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], k=df.index.size)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

cmap = factor_cmap('B', Dark2[3], ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
p.vbar(x='index', top='A', width=0.7, color=cmap, line_width=2, source=source)
show(p)
```

However, if I try to do *the same thing* with a line chart

```
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(x='index', y='A', color=cmap, line_width=2, source=source)
show(p)
```

I get the following value error

```
ValueError: expected an element of either Enum('aliceblue', 'antiquewhite', 'aqua', 'aquamarine', 'azure', 'beige', 'bisque', 'black', 'blanchedalmond', 'blue', 'blueviolet', 'brown', 'burlywood', 'cadetblue', 'chartreuse', 'chocolate', 'coral', 'cornflowerblue', 'cornsilk', 'crimson', 'cyan', 'darkblue', 'darkcyan', 'darkgoldenrod', 'darkgray', 'darkgreen', 'darkgrey', 'darkkhaki', 'darkmagenta', 'darkolivegreen', 'darkorange', 'darkorchid', 'darkred', 'darksalmon', 'darkseagreen', 'darkslateblue', 'darkslategray', 'darkslategrey', 'darkturquoise', 'darkviolet', 'deeppink', 'deepskyblue', 'dimgray', 'dimgrey', 'dodgerblue', 'firebrick', 'floralwhite', 'forestgreen', 'fuchsia', 'gainsboro', 'ghostwhite', 'gold', 'goldenrod', 'gray', 'green', 'greenyellow', 'grey', 'honeydew', 'hotpink', 'indianred', 'indigo', 'ivory', 'khaki', 'lavender', 'lavenderblush', 'lawngreen', 'lemonchiffon', 'lightblue', 'lightcoral', 'lightcyan', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'lightgray', 'lightgreen', 'lightgrey', 'lightpink', 'lightsalmon', 'lightseagreen', 'lightskyblue', 'lightslategray', 'lightslategrey', 'lightsteelblue', 'lightyellow', 'lime', 'limegreen', 'linen', 'magenta', 'maroon', 'mediumaquamarine', 'mediumblue', 'mediumorchid', 'mediumpurple', 'mediumseagreen', 'mediumslateblue', 'mediumspringgreen', 'mediumturquoise', 'mediumvioletred', 'midnightblue', 'mintcream', 'mistyrose', 'moccasin', 'navajowhite', 'navy', 'oldlace', 'olive', 'olivedrab', 'orange', 'orangered', 'orchid', 'palegoldenrod', 'palegreen', 'paleturquoise', 'palevioletred', 'papayawhip', 'peachpuff', 'peru', 'pink', 'plum', 'powderblue', 'purple', 'red', 'rosybrown', 'royalblue', 'saddlebrown', 'salmon', 'sandybrown', 'seagreen', 'seashell', 'sienna', 'silver', 'skyblue', 'slateblue', 'slategray', 'slategrey', 'snow', 'springgreen', 'steelblue', 'tan', 'teal', 'thistle', 'tomato', 'turquoise', 'violet', 'wheat', 'white', 'whitesmoke', 'yellow', 'yellowgreen'), Regex('^#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$'), Regex('^rgba\\(((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d{1,2}|\\d\\d?)\\s*,\\s*?){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d{1,2}|\\d\\d?)\\s*,\\s*([01]\\.?\\d*?)\\)'), Regex('^rgb\\(((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d{1,2}|\\d\\d?)\\s*,\\s*?){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1\\d{1,2}|\\d\\d?)\\s*?\\)'), Tuple(Byte(Int, 0, 255), Byte(Int, 0, 255), Byte(Int, 0, 255)), Tuple(Byte(Int, 0, 255), Byte(Int, 0, 255), Byte(Int, 0, 255), Percent) or RGB, got {'field': 'B', 'transform': CategoricalColorMapper(id='3465', ...)}
```

Where did I go wrong here?

I can workaround that by creating a pivot table on the values of `'B'` and plotting a line for each value. The expected output would be something like this
[image]

However, I need to specifiy every single value and every single color by hand and this will break down every single time the unique values change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` draws a single line, which is always only a single color along its entire length. There is nothing to map, it just expects the one color for the one line. That is the immediate reason what you are trying does not work.

You might think about it this way: If your CDS has columns with 10 points and you plot bars, then you get 10 bars, each can have a different colors corresponding to on of the 10 values in some column. But pass the same data to line, you only get one line, which only has *nine* line segments (between the 10 points). That does not match up with the 10 factors to map for the column, so what exactly would you expect to happen there?

It you want to draw multiple lines, you could use `factor_cmap` together with `multi_line` to give each separate line a different color according to some categorical column. In fact if you simply want to use `multi_line` to plot a single line that can be mapped in the browser with a `factor_cmap` that would also work (you would need to nest the line data one level deeper, as `multi_line` expects a "list of lists").

But it's probably just easier to figure out the single color color for a single line Python, and pass that as `color`.

Comment: That's a good point. I tried the same code with `p.multi_line(xs='index', ys='A', color=cmap, line_width=2, source=source)` and it runs without errors now. However the resulting figure is emtpy. Do you have an idea why that happens?

Comment: `multi_line` expects a "list of lists" i.e. it's a column of *arrays* where each subarray is for one line. You would need to nest the `xs` and `ys` values one level deeper.

Comment: Hmm, that unfortunately does not get simpler than. Also, the categorical values are repeating. So rather than 9 line segments its more like I have 3-4 points per category. And I want a different colored line connecting the points in each category. I don't see why line would not do this. I also get multiple bars instead of only one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting. `line` takes a list of points, and draws a single line between them. There is nothing built in to bokeh that would draw a single line with more than one color.

Comment: The "3-4 points per category" is irrelevant: there are sill 10 factors total, and only 9 segments, so it simply does not make sense. I'm not aware of any plotting library that does anything different in this regard. Some (few) will allow a continuous distance-based mapping along a line, but that is different than this situation with categorical factors. If you want the line split up, you will need to split it up explicitly.

Comment: I edited the original question and attached a picture. I dont see why line shoule not be able to segment the data itself according to the values in column B

Comment: That picture shows multiple lines. So I can only reiterate my earlier suggetsions: multiple calls to `line` with each color specified explicity, or one call to `multi_line` which could use a mapper to color multiple lines (specified with nested data). Regardless of what you want, those are the options that exist. There is nothing anywhere in Bokeh to automatically segment lines according to any criteria.